# export node_modules in yarn berry for aws lambda layers

Tags: aws-lambda, yarnpkg-v2

currently we're using multiple yarn *1.x* projects to deploy code to aws.

to export the dependencies for lambda-layers we're currently using
`yarn install --production --modules-folder layer/nodejs/node_modules`

now we'd like to migrate to **yarn berry** to utilise local package references,  however the `--modules-folder` option does not exist anymore.

**Is there a way to archive the same thing with yarn berry?**

for context, this is my .yarnrc file:

```
nmHoistingLimits: workspaces

nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript"
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-berry.js
```

Comment: did you ever manage to find a solution to this / migrate to Berry?

Comment: so they said it is not and will never be supported, however I could solve my problem by using esbuild. It bundles all your dependencies into one file that you can execute. 
Perfect for the lambda use-case.

Comment: another learning:
when using npm workspaces it's possible to run:
`npm -w @foo/lambda --omit=dev ls --depth=9999 --parseable`

this gives a list of prod dependencies. Should be pretty easy to build a script from there on that copies and zips them